# arrangements package - permutations of order 128

Tags: r, permutation

I am trying to run a simple permutation of 'x' and 'y' across 128 spaces using the arrangements package on R.

I keep getting the following error message :

```
    Error in permutations(test, k = 128, replace = TRUE) : too many results
```

The code that I ran was as follows:

```
    library(arrangements)
    test <- c('x','y')
    permutations(test, k = 128, replace = TRUE)
```

sessionInfo() is as follows:

```
    R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
    Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
    Running under: macOS Monterey 12.2.1
```

Is there a work around I can use? I am also experimenting with the parallel package. Please advice.

Comment: The result is a matrix with `2^128 == 3.402824e+38`, how can you expect a result?

Comment: Understandable. I need to run random samples on the output. With Josephs method, I will run a random sample on n=2^128 and use the result to generate specific rows. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's way too many results as @Rui points out in the comments:

```
npermutations(2, 128, replace=TRUE, bigz = TRUE)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 340282366920938463463374607431768211456
```

How about using the `skip` and `nitem` parameters? This allows a user to retrieve a handful of results at a time.

```
## First 100,000 results
system.time(res <- permutations(c('x', 'y'), 128, replace = TRUE, nitem = 1e5))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.146   0.000   0.146

## process res

## Next 100,000 results
res <- permutations(c('x', 'y'), 128, replace = TRUE, skip = 1e5, nitem = 1e5)

## process res

## 100,000 results starting at leixcographical index 1e19 + 1
## n.b. need to use strings or bigz type
res <- permutations(c('x', 'y'), 128, replace = TRUE,
                    skip = "10000000000000000000", nitem = 1e5)

## process res
## etc.
```

This can easily be generalized to parallel processing if needed.